# Edge iterators are returning the wrong result

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin

I'm trying to work with a specific edge in my graph, but referring to it by its id isn't working.

I can grab the edge by a property query:

```
g.E.filter{it.TRANSACTION_ID =='15405'}
==> e[3042][1429-SOLD->11]
```

When I inspect this edge, it's the one I'm interested in. So I try to specify it by its index, `3042`:

```
g.E[3042]
==> e[3335][1028-SOLD->2126]
```

Why is the console returning `3335`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem. Edges in Neo4j are not ordered sequentially when you iterate through all edges. I believe what you want to do is:

```
g.e(3042)
```

What you are doing is doing a full "table scan."

Comment: Please do *not* add unrelated links to your posts, such as links to your website. I am editing those links out to avoid your posts being mistaken for spam.